# PostgreSQL delete duplicate rows with inner join

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
DELETE c1 FROM component c1 INNER JOIN component c2 WHERE c1.id > c2.id AND c1.key = c2.key;
```

i am getting the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "c1"
LINE 1: DELETE c1 FROM component c1 INNER JOIN component c2 WHERE c1...
```

what is the problem with my query?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `JOIN` syntax to join to the table being deleted from.  The correct syntax is to use `USING` instead:

```
DELETE FROM component c1 
USING component c2 
WHERE c1.id > c2.id AND c1.key = c2.key;
```

That means you have to put the join condition in the WHERE clause rather than an ON, but you were already doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id` is unique, I would phrase this in Postgres as:

```
DELETE component c USING
       (SELECT c2.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key ORDER BY id) as seqnum
        FROM component c2
       ) c2
    WHERE c2.id = c.id AND c2.seqnum > 1;
```

Or using a correlated subquery:

```
DELETE component c
    WHERE c.id > (SELECT MIN(c2.id)
                  FROM component c2
                  WHERE c2.key = c.key
                 );
```

Your version (which uses SQL Server syntax) can find multiple matches for each row being deleted.

Comment: you can't have a derived table in the `FROM` clause in Postgres. You need `delete from component using ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Do you know why Postgres has `USING` for `DELETE` but allows `FROM` for `UPDATE`?

Comment: No idea. Neither is standard.

Answer (score 0):

Remove c1 from your query:

```
DELETE FROM component c1 
    INNER JOIN component c2 
    WHERE c1.id > c2.id 
    AND c1.key = c2.key
```

Comment: i am getting the following error

```ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
LINE 1: DELETE FROM component c1 INNER JOIN component c2 WHERE c1.id...```
                                 ^

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple with `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM component c 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM component WHERE key = c.key and id < c.id)
```